# How to detect email platform used with AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, outlook, gmail, interactive-email

**Problem**: I used the Interactive email form for my Email Template, with a *description* related to it (*description* stay above the Interactive Email form, in a different block).

But since Outlook hasn't supported this feature (Interactive email), the email is hidden when I tested with Outlook, thus leading the *description* to stand alone out of context.

**Question**: Is there a way to hide the *description* based on the email platform the users use (Outlook vs Gmail)?

If not, is there a way from your experience to handle this issue?

Comment: this block is just using MSO tags to hide the block and provide fall back image, you could do the same for any other content block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMPScript is a server-side language.

Once your email leaves the system, AMPScript is completely out of the picture.  After the email has been rendered for a user, AMPScript has completely turned into a calculated result and is not physically present in mails that land in any inbox.

So it is 100% impossible to use AMPScript to read anything out about the recipient and how they view your email. (=client side).

If it were feasible - email clients would block / strip it. This would be potentially dangerous and could be exploited by malicious actors.

The only thing you could do with AMPScript / server side script (don't.) is to personalize based on the domain of a recipient's email address, but that doesn't help much. It's not the domain that's relevant, but also the device / email client (i.e. gmail app, gmail web, outlook, apple mail, thunderbird...) and you have no way of determining that before sendout. It's not even logically possible, as the same email can be viewed on multiple devices by the same person, at the same time.

You would need client side script ("script that stays in the email after it left the server") for such a thing.

Which leaves these two options:
make your description part of the interactive form or remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation! I tried to put the description inside the Interactive form, but it seems that we also don't have that kind of option either. 
The Interactive form is an isolated content, and only contains several options for the form, but not the description. Or there is a method to do it that I haven't figured it out?

Comment: Honestly, no idea. I am in a country where so many widespread email clients don't support it that I've never used it.

Comment: The method that should be used here is to determine the Outlook version is the Outlook conditional tag. Something like this:

<!--[if mso]> <![endif]-->